# How to set color after pathogen load colorscheme in VIM

Tags: vim

I use pathogen as VIM plugin manager, and [jelly beans](https://github.com/nanotech/jellybeans.vim) as default colorscheme, I want to define line number color by myself, so I set `hi CursorLineNr guifg=yellow` in vimrc, but pathogen will load jelly beans color replace my setting, how to override it.

Comment: Just add that line after `colorscheme jellybeans`.

Comment: It's not work, I tried it~

Comment: Did you read the README?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to fork and modify the colorscheme, it's best to install this whenever the colorscheme changes:

```
:autocmd ColorScheme * hi CursorLineNr guifg=yellow
```

You could even add a conditional on `g:colors_name` and choose different customizations for different colorschemes.

Comment: The (real) answer is in the readme. But why RTFM when it's so easy to ask random strangers from the other side of the planet? Never take responsibility, right?

Comment: You are the real MVP.